# Calling a function within a function creates loop?

Tags: python

I was teaching a python intro course this morning , one of my student came with a question I could not answer

I create a function and within that function, I'm calling the same function and it is looping

```
def prenom():
    print("Nadia")
    prenom()
```

Why?

Comment: What do you mean why? Why wouldn't it?! Unless you shadow the function itself with a parameter or local variable, it's still accessible within itself.

Comment: The keyword for you is recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called *recursion* with no base-case.

You call a function, it (recursively) calls itself and so on. There's no stopping condition, so it will loop forever. This is how infinite loops are created in assembly.

Comment: infinite up to stack overflow

Comment: @Holloway, yes, eventually, you'll end up with a stack overflow

Answer (score 1):

Obviously it will loop.
You haven't set a terminating condition.
Set `exit()` before calling the function again and you will terminate it successfully (and by termination I mean you will end the program).

Alternatively you may use an if-else condition

Comment: Hi @uddeshiya-singh, where would you put the `exit()`?

Comment: in the block in which u defined your function..just before calling that function. (when executed, it will ask for ur consent to terminate the program)

Comment: Hi @uddeshiya-singh, would you mind putting an example, please?